# Processor issues with LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, left-join

This may or may not be a simple question.

I have a query which selects all locations within a mile radius around a provided latitude and longitude. That part works perfectly, but I have additional information inside of another table that I would like to match to it. I've tried LEFT JOIN, but it's timing out.

```
SELECT *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(40.7143528) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lon ) - radians(-74.0059731) ) + sin( radians(40.7143528) ) 
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM locations
LEFT JOIN informations ON
locations.name = informations.name
HAVING distance < 1
```

Here is what I would like this query to do:

1. Provide all matching locations within a mile radius (works)
2. Obtain the name of those stores (works)
3. Match those names against the names of each store in the "informations" table
4. Join all of the information in the matching rows together, where "locations.name" and "informations.name" match

The above query seems like it wants to work. I don't get any errors and it shows as valid in [any MySQL formatter I use](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm). However, I think I'm making an error somewhere which causes my tiny server to max processor usage.

To a more experienced set of eyes, would you see a reason why this would occur? Other than my server being near useless, of which I'm aware.

Comment: Make your initial query a subquery of the main query, and left join that resulting relation to the new table (with additional information). That should give you performance back.

Comment: The result will looklike this: `SELECT * from ( query#1 ) locations left join informations on location.name =informations.name`

Comment: how long does it take to finish? 100% cpu just means your cpu gets busy, that's actually a good thing.

Comment: Consider using PostGIS when working with geographic coordinates.

Comment: Sebas: Well, the last time I ran it, roughly 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your initial query a sub-query of the main query, and left join that resulting relation to the new table (with additional information). That should give you performance back

The result will look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM( 
  SELECT *, 
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(40.7143528) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
  * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(-74.0059731) ) + sin( radians(40.7143528) ) 
  * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM locations
) locations 
LEFT JOIN informations 
  ON location.name =informations.name
```

The HAVING clause is of course part of query #1.

I use SQL SERVER typically, so the syntax may not be quite right for MYSQL.

Comment: This looks excellent and is most likely what I need, but I'm having trouble tackling the syntax. Every incarnation I've tried of shoving everything in the aforementioned `--query#1` results in syntax errors. This might be much to ask, but would you mind taking a shot at filling in `--query#1` so I can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, actually -- it's joining the tables properly, but all the values seem to be null. I'm trying to figure that one out right now. I suspect the data doesn't match for some reason.

Comment: Correct; there were some inaccuracies in my data. This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Not only has this helped complete the tool I was building, but it significantly advanced my understanding of MySQL syntax.